# How to properly use the SCAN function in SAS

Tags: sas

I have two columns in SAS that list data as organized below:

```
|--------act_route_path --------| Off_At_Loc |-------Misroute_Loc

HOU-FTW-AMA-AQE-FMT  |-----   AMA-----|---------- ?????
```

I am creating a new column, Misroute_Loc, in which I wish to populate using the Off_At_Loc column. I am attempting to use the SCAN function to accomplish this, but am not having any success. In the above example I want the output into Misroute_Loc to be FTW.

The code I am using looks like the below:

```
Misroute_Loc=scan(act_route_path,Greater,-4,3);
```

The greater column is telling me the position in which `AMA(Off_At_Loc)` begins.

I can get the above code to run, however it is not pulling back FTW as I want it to.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking.  What are the variable names? What are the values of the variables?  Where the heck did `GREATER` come from?  If you want to pull `FTW` out of  `HOU-FTW-AMA-AQE-FMT` then use `scan(act_route_path,2,'-')`.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Sorry for the confusion, I am new to SAS and SQL and it’s obvious as every question I ask doesn’t come across clearly. The greater column is one I have created to find the MAX function of two other columns.

Comment: Please follow the guidelines for posting a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  - this makes it much easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing path is a - delimited list of places and you want to extract the place in path before the off place.

```
data want;

  path = 'HOU-FTW-AMA-AQE-FMT';
  off = 'AMA';

  * find the off place (as a word);
  p = indexw(path, trim(off), '-');

  * scan backwards one word from path part up to the off place;
  if p > 2 then before_off = scan(substr(1,path,p-2), -1, '-');
run;
```

Comment: Should the value of BEFORE_OFF be FTW?

Comment: Oops, typo in substr.  Should be `substr(path,1,p-2)`. Will fix